# How accurate is the iPhone's accerometer - is it possible to draw a relatively accurate motion path of the phone's position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, accelerometer

Given that the phone starts in a staionary position, it would be possible to work out the motion path of where the phone travels. (Just integrate acceleration twice numerically to get a distance vs time graph).

How accurate would this path be? Would shaking the phone mess up the accuracy? Would the gyroscope on some devices help or improve this in any way?

If it is possible to produce a reasonable result, how would I go about starting this - or even better, is there any open source code that does this already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal experience testing this didn't pan out so well...

The second integral drifts fast enough that the position is meaningless within seconds, and that's just for linear motion. Shake or twist the phone and it goes out of whack almost immediately. The gyroscope doesn't help much with this, either.

The results were so bad that I didn't spend very long investigating. Perhaps others have had more success.

Answer (score 1):

Double integration amplifies acceleration noise so fast that even a tiny bit of rounding or quantization error will send the double integrals estimate of your motion path out of the building in seconds.

Some way of checking the devices absolute position, such as using the video camera on some fiducial mark, might work much better.

Comment: One way around this might be to 'gate' the noise - so that a small amount of acceleration gets rounded down to zero. i.e. Only big, confident movements get accounted for. For my purpose - detecting if the phone moves to a different room - this _might_ work... still, I can see it would be very hard to get right.

Comment: @Jordan : A big confident acceleration paired with a less confident de-acceleration (that got gated to zero) would still leave you with non-zero velocity, and thus zooming out of the room and out of the other room as well.

Answer (score 1):

Marcelo is correct that this is, at best, very challenging with the hardware currently available. It was tempting to try, but I concluded that it was infeasible due to noise, drift, and the limited range of the accelerometer. The maximum sensor reading is approximately 2G. This permits pretty high resolution readings for fine motion, but prevents you from measuring the magnitude of large accelerations.

EDIT: I am unable to find a reference for this, but I remember the sensitivity to be ~0.018 G.